# NSCharacterSet - append another character set

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-foundation

I would like to create a character set that includes all of its own characters, as well as those from another character set. Append in other words.

I thought there'd be an obvious way, but after control-space completion in the IDE, and then poking around the docs, I couldn't fine anything.

I can see how to append all the characters from a string. But I need to append the characters from another set. I guess I could to-string the second set, if there's a to-string method.

How do I do this?

Comment: Did you look at the methods in the NSMutableCharacterSet reference?

Comment: @rdelmar Yes, the mutable set lets me add characters from a string or range. But how to I just add another instance of NSCharacterSet?

Comment: formIntersectionWithCharacterSet: lets you add one index set to another. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, that was helpful. I didn't see those methods. . (NB: formUnion is the actual one I want).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are probably seaching for this method in `NSMutableCharacterSet` :

```
- (void)formUnionWithCharacterSet:(NSCharacterSet *)otherSet
```

From Doc:

> Modifies the receiver so it contains all characters that exist in
>   either the receiver or otherSet.

Comment: From what I can tell all the character sets are NSCharacterSet so they don't have access to the formUnionWithCharacterSet method. How do we combine multiple NSCharacterSets?

Comment: @LukePighetti use mutableCopy on a NSCharacterSet: [[NSCharaterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] mutableCopy]

Answer (score 15):

For Swift 3:

```
let fullCharset = aCharset.union(anotherCharset)
```