# Value of tuple Void (aka ()) has no member "isSuperset"

Tags: swift, textfield, nscharacterset

I created a union between two character sets to be able to use a period with the decimalDigits character set.

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn     range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

            let allowed = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
            let period = CharacterSet.init(charactersIn: ".")
            let both = CFCharacterSetUnion(allowed as! CFMutableCharacterSet, period as CFCharacterSet)

            let characterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: string)

            return both.isSuperset(of: characterSet as CharacterSet)
        }
```

however, returning "both.isSuperset(of: characterSet as CharacterSet)". how to correct?

Update 1:
Errors displayed with the current suggested answer
[image]

Update 2: 
latest update
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this instead:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn     range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    var allowed = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
    let period = CharacterSet.init(charactersIn: ".")
    allowed.formUnion(period)

    //UNCOMMENT when isSuperset is working
    //let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
    //return allowed.isSuperset(of: characterSet)

    // Swift 3 appropriate solution 
    let isSuperset = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: allowed.inverted) == nil
    return isSuperset
}
```

the basis for which [I found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18809149/nscharacterset-append-another-character-set).

Even better, make "`allowed`" (or "`both`", whatever you decide to name it) a property that gets created in `viewDidLoad` so you don't recreate and union the character sets each time a character is typed.

Comment: Would you be able to continue with the answer? I apologize, haha, I'm receiving an error with your above answer. Ill post in a second

Comment: Turns out you ran into a bug! [`isSuperset` doesn't work properly in Swift 3](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63262)

Comment: regardless, thank you so much for a workable solution! ive been racking my brain over this for hours.

Comment: Michael, wanted to ask for further clarification. Why is it that when we set the isSuperset variable, we add the "== nil"? Why can't we simply say "= true" considering the func returns a bool?

Comment: Basically what that line is saying is:  "return the range of any characters in the string that match characters ***NOT*** found in the allowed set".  So if a range is not found, `string` is covered by that superset (no range returned equals nil which makes `isSuperset` true).  If a range is found, there's an invalid / not-allowed character in it (i.e. `isSuperset` is set to false and the `string` won't be changed) Hopefully this makes sense?